# Extracting row as plot title in GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

```
-Empty line here-
LED:GREEN   FREQUENCY:1 BRIGHTNESS:50
Colour  State   Time(s)
GREEN   1   0.000000
GREEN   1   0.020000
GREEN   1   0.040000
GREEN   1   0.060000
GREEN   1   0.080000
GREEN   1   0.100000
.
.
.
LED:RED FREQUENCY2:1    BRIGHTNESS2:25
Colour  State   Time(s)
RED 1   0.000000
RED 1   0.020000
RED 1   0.040000
RED 1   0.060000
RED 1   0.080000
RED 1   0.100000
```

I have the above .txt file as my data file and im trying to extract the rows with first column LED:GREEN/LED RED to use as my plot title for each respective graph in my multiplot.

I have the following code:

```
f(x,y)= (x eq "GREEN"? y :1/0);

p(x,y)= (x eq "RED"? y :1/0);

plot 'abc.txt' u 3:(f(strcol(1),$2)):"LED:GREEN" with lines linecolor "green";

plot 'abc.txt' u 3:(p(strcol(1),$2)) with lines linecolor "red";
```

Is there any way to extract those rows to use as plot title?
ie. `LED:GREEN  FREQUENCY:1 BRIGHTNESS:50` and `LED:RED FREQUENCY2:1    BRIGHTNESS2:25`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How many empty lines are there between the last `GREEN ...` line and `LED:RED... ` line? None, one or serval? Are you flexible with the data format or is it fixed and given?

Comment: @theozh Hey thanks for the welcome. It is populated with datas till 60seconds for each colour, and data format is flexible to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a graph title has to be done before the plot command. So, in order to extract a line you need to go through the data file. You could do this via an external tool, but I prefer (if possible) *gnuplot-only* solutions.

If you can slightly change your data, I would recommend to insert two empty lines between your GREEN-part and RED-part. With this, you can address the blocks simply via `index` (block index is zero-based) (check `help index`).

You can (mis)use `stats` to go through data and store some parts into variables.
If you `set datafile separator "\n"`, a complete line can be accessed as `strcol(1)` (check `help strcol`). Since you only need the first line (row index is zero-based) you can limit it by using `every ::::0` (check `help every`).

**Data:** `SO77401935.dat`

```
LED:GREEN   FREQUENCY:1 BRIGHTNESS:50
Colour  State   Time(s)
GREEN   1   0.000000
GREEN   1   0.020000
GREEN   0   0.040000
GREEN   1   0.060000
GREEN   1   0.080000
GREEN   1   0.100000


LED:RED FREQUENCY2:1    BRIGHTNESS2:25
Colour  State   Time(s)
RED 1   0.000000
RED 1   0.020000
RED 1   0.040000
RED 1   0.060000
RED 0   0.080000
RED 1   0.100000
```

**Script:**

```
### get title from a row
reset session

FILE = "SO77401935.dat"

set datafile separator "\n"
stats FILE index 0 every ::::0 u (myTitle1 = strcol(1)) nooutput
stats FILE index 1 every ::::0 u (myTitle2 = strcol(1)) nooutput
set datafile separator whitespace

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set title myTitle1
    plot FILE index 0 u 3:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" lw 2
    
    set title myTitle2
    plot FILE index 1 u 3:2 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green" lw 2
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro, that was exactly what i was looking for and the script works well. Agree with you on the gnuplot-only solution! There is however an warning message regarding the two stats line: "All points out of range". Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: @ys086 which version of gnuplot are you using? Do you get a graph despite the warning?

Comment: im using v5.4, and yea i do get the graph despite the warning, just wondering how i can the warning

Comment: @ys086 with the example above don't get this warning. It's difficult to test without your real data and the your actual script.

Comment: i will look into it with my data, thanks for the help. cheers